Access instance attribute docstring
According to PEP 258, it is possible to define an instance attribute docstring in the __init__ function, as in the given example:
g = 'module attribute (module-global variable)'
"""This is g's docstring."""

class AClass:

    c = 'class attribute'
    """This is AClass.c's docstring."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Method __init__'s docstring."""

        self.i = 'instance attribute'
        """This is self.i's docstring."""

def f(x):
    """Function f's docstring."""
    return x**2

f.a = 1
"""Function attribute f.a's docstring."""

However, entering instance = AClass() then instance.i? in the console does not give me the docstring of the class attribute, but the str docstring instead. How can I access instance.i's docstring (i.e. """This is self.i's docstring""")?

That (rejected!) PEP only tells you what docutils will look for: "While this may serve as an interesting design document for the now-independent docutils, it is no longer slated for inclusion in the standard library."

Oops, thanks for mentioning that it was rejected, I completely missed that!

It is however mentioned in PEP 257 https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/ which is active.
